# developing laravel project without internet on remote desktop

Tags: laravel-5, remote-desktop, offline-mode

I am working in an organization where i Have to start projects in laravel, but the problem there is that we are working on remote desktop i.e., without internet and without copy & paste of code. Is there any way to develop my web applications on remote desktop?
can I download the laravel source code and start development?
If Yes, how will I update packages or make commands on composer as composer downloads from internet?

Comment: you can download and install everything on a machine with internet access and then copy the files over and work locally from there.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel source code can be downloaded to your local machine or remote computer and you start using it straight away without the need of internet  (except for default Laravel bootstrap, google fonts, which can be downloaded by you, or you can ignore it completely)

The second thing composer doesn’t need connection at all, its local,  it just generate files from command line.

However For packages yes you definitely need Internet so you will need connection.